# Is there a name for this type of linear partial differential equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I came across the following form of first order linear partial differential equation and I was wondering if there is a name for it?

$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = h(x,y),
$$

where $g(x,y)$ as well as $h(x,y)$ are given and $f(x,y)$ is the unknown.

For the interested: It appears in this [paper](http://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/abs/10.1175/1520-0450%281964%29003%3C0685%3ACOTCIA%3E2.0.CO%3B2), equation (10) when solving for the transverse circulation, i.e. radial and vertical wind fields in an idealised hurricane model.

If there is no name, is there maybe anything analytical one learn about this equation?

Comment: The left hand side looks like the $z$ component of a cross product between the gradients of $f$ and $g$. In fact, if $f$ is independent of $z$, this would exactly be the cross products of the gradients since the other two pieces would evaluate to zero.

Comment: Thank you Cameron Williams, I had noticed that, too. However I don't see how to exploit this in solving the equation. Does someone have a suggestion? Of course I can discretise it and solve it numerically, but I'm interested in analytical insights.

Comment: Perhaps the method of characteristics would be useful. The technique works really well for first order linear PDEs.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Cameron Williams said, this is a first-order linear PDE, to which the method of characteristics can be applied. Your equation has a special form thanks to $g$; in fact, the left hand side of the equation is known as the [Poisson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket) of $f$ and $g$. A consequence of this is that the characteristic curves of the PDE are precisely the level sets $g(x,y)=c$.

Let's see why. Let $(x(t), y(t))$ be any solution curve of the ODE
$$\begin{split}
x'(t) &= -g_y(x(t),y(t)) \\
y'(t)  &= g_x(x(t),y(t)) 
\end{split}\tag{1}$$
(I prefer using subscripts for derivatives.)
This curve is a level curve of $g$, because
$$
\frac{d}{dt}g(x(t),y(t)) = x'g_x+y'g_y= -g_yg_x+g_xg_y = 0 
$$
Also, the derivative of unknown function $f$ along this curve is 
$$
\frac{d}{dt}f(x(t),y(t)) = x'f_x+y'f_y= -g_yf_x+g_xf_y = h(x(t),y(t))
\tag{2}$$
Thus, the problem of solving the PDE splits into parametrizing level curves of $g$, and then integrating $h$ along those curves.